# Reverse a foreach loop action

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach

I want to convert/find each of my string characters to (int) and reverse this operation.
I manage to do the first part,but the seconds one is giving me some problems.

```
string input;
string encrypt = ""; string decrypt = "";

input = textBox.Text;
foreach (char c in input)
{
    int x = (int)c;
    string s = x.ToString();
    encrypt += s;
}
MessageBox.Show(encrypt);

foreach (int i in encrypt)
{
    char c = (char)i;
    string s = c.ToString();
    decrypt += c;
}
MessageBox.Show(decrypt);
```

Thanks!

Comment: No it is not reversible. what does this mean for ex `12345`? `123` and `45` or `12` and `345`?

Comment: You can`t this way since each character turns into a number with two or three digits. Try use an array to store the converted characters in order to convert them back to string

Comment: Let's say the input is 'A'. You're then converting the char 'A' the value 65.  Then you call .ToString() on it. So encrypt now hold "65" (a string). Then you're looping through each character in encrypt (6, then 5), and converting it to a char - rather than taking '65' and converting it to a char. Take a look at asciitable.com - what you're doing doesn't really make sense. Give us a broader idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fixed program according to my advise above

```
        string encrypt = ""; string decrypt = "";

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        var length = input.Length;
        int[] converted = new int[length];
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            int x = input[index];
            string s = x.ToString();
            encrypt += s;
            converted[index] = x;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(encrypt);
        for (int index = 0; index < converted.Length; index++)
        {
            char c = (char)converted[index];
            string s = c.ToString();
            decrypt += s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(decrypt);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as is, because you're adding numbers to a string with no padding.

Let's assume the first three letter's values are '1','2','3', you'll have a string with "123".
Now, if you know each letter is 1 int length, you're good, but what happens if 12 is valid? and 23?

This might not be a "real" issues in your case because the values will probably be all 2 ints long, but it's very lacking (unless it's homework, in which case, oh well ...)

The ascii values for the alphabet will go from 65 for `A` to 122 `z`.

You can either pad them (say 3 chars per number, so 065 for `A`, and so on), delimit them (have ".", and split the string on that), use an array (like shahar's suggestion), lists, etc etc ...

Comment: This is the right answer. The fundamental issue is assuming that `int x = (int)c; string s = x.ToString();` only adds one character to the encrypt string.

Answer (score 1):

In Your scenario, encryption may give output as you expected but its hard to decrypt the encrypted text using such mechanism. so I just do some customization on your code and make it workable here.

i suggest a similar one here:

```
        string input;
        string encrypt = ""; string decrypt = "";
        int charCount = 0;
        input = "textBox.Text";
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            int x = (int)c;
            string s = x.ToString("000");
            encrypt += s;
            charCount++;
        }
        // MessageBox.Show(encrypt);
        while (encrypt.Length > 0)
        {
            int item = Int32.Parse(encrypt.Substring(0, 3));
            encrypt = encrypt.Substring(3);
            char c = (char)item;
            string s = c.ToString();
            decrypt += c;
        }
```

Reason for your code is not working:

1. You have declared `encrypt` as string and iterate through each integer in that string value, it is quiet not possible.
2. if you make that loop to iterate through each characters in that string value again it gives confusion. as :
   lets take `S` as your input. its equivalent int value is `114` so if you make a looping means it will give `1`,`1`,`4`, you will not get `s` back from it.